# Need help defining a function for text based game

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to code out a function for this project. I am new to python and am taking a class online for it. I am trying to define a function that will read what room my player is in and to give the riddle associated with it. so far this is what I have, there is another dictionary that current_room works with. I just keep getting key errors when trying to test run. If there is a better way to do this as well, please let me know.

EDIT: updating with whole code

```
# The dictionary links a room to other rooms.
rooms = {'Warehouse Storage': {'name': 'Warehouse Storage', 'south': 'Stamping Area',
                               'text': 'You are in the Warehouse Storage.'},
         'Machine Shop': {'name': 'Machine Shop', 'east': 'Scrap Pile', 'south': 'Staging Area',
                          'text': 'You are in the Machine Shop.'},
         'Front Offices': {'name': 'Front Offices', 'west': 'Lunchroom',
                           'text': 'You are in Front Offices.'},
         'Stamping Area': {'name': 'Stamping Area', 'west': 'Staging Area', 'north': 'Warehouse Storage',
                           'text': 'You are in the Stamping Area'},
         'Loading Docks': {'name': 'Loading Docks', 'east': 'Staging Area',
                           'text': 'You are in the Loading Docks'},
         'Staging Area': {'name': 'Staging Area', 'east': 'Stamping Area', 'west': 'Loading Docks',
                          'south': 'Lunchroom', 'north': 'Machine Shop',
                          'text': 'You are in the Staging Area'},
         'Lunchroom': {'name': 'Lunchroom', 'north': 'Staging Area', 'east': 'Front Offices',
                       'text': 'You are in the Lunchroom'},
         'Scrap Pile': {'name': 'Scrap Pile', 'west': 'Machine Shop',
                        'text': 'You are in the Scrap Pile'}
         }

riddles = {'Warehouse Storage': {'name': 'Warehouse Storage', 'question': '', 'answer': ''},
           'Machine Shop': {'name': 'Machine Shop', 'question': '', 'answer': ''},
           'Stamping Area': {'name': 'Stamping Area', 'question': '', 'answer': ''},
           'Staging Area': {'name': 'Staging Area', 'question': '', 'answer': ''},
           'Lunchroom': {'name': 'Lunchroom', 'question': 'riddle', 'answer': 'yes'},
           'Scrap Pile': {'name': 'Scrap Pile', 'question': '', 'answer': ''}
           }


# define function that reads room and prompts user with riddle
def room_puzzle(current_room):
    global user_inventory
    if current_room in riddles.keys():
        riddle = input(f'{riddles[current_room]["question"]} \n').strip()

        if riddle == riddles[current_room]['answer']:
            user_inventory += 1
            print('You gained a key')

        else:
            print('that is incorrect')

            return user_inventory
    else:
        print("no such room")

# determine command regardless of capitalization
def dir_input(text):
    if text.upper().startswith('W'):
        return 'west'
    elif text.upper().startswith('N'):
        return 'north'
    elif text.upper().startswith('S'):
        return 'south'
    elif text.upper().startswith('E'):
        return 'east'
    elif text.upper().startswith('Q'):
        return 'quit'


directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']
current_room = rooms['Front Offices']

print('Would you like to play a game?')
start = input()
game_start = False
user_inventory = 0 # start at zero
if start == 'yes' or start == 'Yes':
    game_start = True
# game loop
while game_start == True:
    # win condition
    if current_room['name'] == 'Loading Docks':
        if user_inventory == 6:
            print(current_room['text'])
        else:
            print('6 keys are required to enter')
    # display current location
    print()
    print(current_room['text'])
    # get user input
    command = input('\nWhat do you do? ').strip()

    # show inventory
    if command == 'show inventory':
        print('You have {} keys'.format(user_inventory))
    # movement
    elif command in directions:
        command = dir_input(command)
        if command in current_room:
            current_room = rooms[current_room[command]]
            #room_puzzle()
        else:
            # not a valid input
            print("You can't go that way.")
    # quit game
    elif command == 'quit':
        break
    # does not compute
    else:
        print("I don't understand that command.")
```

Comment: Check your key you are trying to access!

Comment: What is the value of `riddles['name']`, in your opinion?

Comment: Would it not be 'Lunchroom'?

Comment: do you want to check whether the `current_room` is `Lunchroom` or not? if yes then the that part is wrong

Comment: I am trying to define a function that will read the room the player enters and pull the riddle from the dictionary. I have 8 rooms I will be putting the riddles in for.

Answer (score 1):

See basically what I observe from the above code is that you want to check whether the `current_room` is equal to `Lunchroom` or not or for any other rooms you have in your riddles dictionary.
So for that, you have to check for the presence of a key in the dictionary not for the values. Also, the below part is incorrect in your code
`if current_room in riddles['name']:`

instead, it should be

`if current_room in riddles.keys():`

and the part of code `if riddle == riddles['answer']:` is incorrect as the you are not passing the right reference to the dictionary key

it should be `if riddle == riddles[current_room]['answer']:`

so here is the correct code with the working demo for you to understand.

```
riddles = {'Lunchroom': {'name': 'Lunchroom', 'question': 'riddle?', 'answer': 'yes'}}

def room_puzzle(current_room):
    global user_inventory
    if current_room in riddles.keys():
        riddle = input('{}'.format(riddles[current_room]['question'])).strip()
        if riddle == riddles[current_room]['answer']: # here you have to define the refrence to the dictionary value, using the parent key first
            # user_inventory += 1
            print('You gained a key')
        else:
            print('that is incorrect')

        # return user_inventory
    else:
        print("no such room")

current_room = 'Lunchroom' #let's assume for now

room_puzzle(current_room)

current_room = 'Someroom' #let's now change the current_room and check that

room_puzzle(current_room)
```

Comment: So I ran this on its own and it works, but once I put it into my actual project, its giving me a TypeError: unhashable type: ‘dict’.

Comment: I can't say directly here what is going wrong on your actual code without even looking at it. Either you post the entire code or share it on discord

Comment: Alright, I posted everything  have so far